# Eclipse Error - Java was started but returned exit code=13

Tags: java, android, eclipse

[image]

After trying to figure out the "No Java JDK/JRE installed" issue and editing the .ini file to indicate what Java JRE to start with, I get this error, and it is very frustrating. I must have done something in the .ini file to make this happen. I tried a few different things to fix this, but it has become quite stressful as I haven't been able to get anything done today, so any help will be appreciated.

I read that this is a conflict between 32 and 64 bit Java and Eclipse, however I am 99% sure they are both 64 bit. 2nd Question is there anyway I can double check I have both 64 bit versions?

Comment: The Java is in `Program Files (x86)` which makes it 32 bit. The Eclipse `--launcher.library` is `.x86_64` which is 64 bit.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that you are trying to start a 64 bit version of Eclipse with a 32 bit version of Java. You can download it from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html)

Start Eclipse with a 64 bit JVM and the problem will go away.

To do so:

```
eclipse.exe -vm c:\path\to\64\bit\bin\javaw.exe
```

You can also update the the first two lines in your eclipse.ini file to use the 64 bit java by default by doing the following:

```
-vm
c:\path\to\64\bit\bin\javaw.exe
```

Also, you can also download a 32 bit version of Eclipse for use with 32 bit Java. The key is that the bitness is the same.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. i was using windows7 with 64 bit OS. I just insert this two line in first line of eclipse.ini file like,

```
-vm
```

C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe (This is path for your javaw.exe)

Answer (score 0):

**Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM** it's not supported in **JDK8**
Just uninstall **JDK8**